# Make a ajax POST call again after the data in success is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I will get the object here based on the data posted. User chooses different filters in data. As user chooses different filters, I want to update the postThis Object and make the Ajax call again with updated object.

```
var postThis = {
  "name": ''
}
$.ajax({
  method:post,
  url:someurl,
  data: postThis
})
.success(function(data) {
  // name has to be updated with value which I get after user chooses it

})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to send another AJAX request in the case where the first one succeeds, with results of the first request then just make another `$.ajax` request like you already have, and pass it the received data:

```
$.ajax({
  method: post,
  url: someurl,
  data: postThis
})
.success(function(data) {
  yourSecondAjaxCall(data);
})

function yourSecondAjaxCall(dataFromFirstAjax) {
  $.ajax({
    method: post,
    url: someurl,
    data: dataFromFirstAjax
  })
  .success(function(data) {
     // do whatever
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simple way to do that is simply nest ajax calls

```
$.ajax({
  method:post,
  url:someurl,
  data: postThis
})
.success(function(data) {
  // name has to be updated with value which I get after user chooses it
      $.ajax({
      method:post,
      url:someurl,
      data: UPDATED_DATA
    })
    .success(function(data) {
    [...]
    }) 
})
```